# Why I'm getting and error in routes config file when trying to pass user data from parent component to child component in React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I try to pass the username from my parent component to the child component in order to show it in the Header (child) I'm getting an error.

No issues if I try to pass the data from child to parent. However, due to project needs, I have to pass the user data from parent to child. I'm getting this error in my routeConfig file and I don't know why:
[image]

Here is the child component:

```js
interface DashboardHeaderProps {
    username: string;
}

const DashboardHeader = ({ username }: DashboardHeaderProps): JSX.Element => {
    const classes = styles.dashboardHeaderStyles();

    return (
        <Box className={classes.container}>
            <Box>
                <Typography className={classes.welcomeText}>Hello {username}, welcome back!</Typography>
            </Box>

            <Box className={classes.logoutContainer}>
                <CustomIcon className={classes.userIcon} icon={icons.userMenu} />
                <Link className={classes.logoutText} onClick={() => logout()}>
                    Logout
                </Link>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );
};

export default DashboardHeader;
```

Here is the parent component:

```js
import { ILoggedInUserData } from "store/slice/auth/authSlice.types";

interface DashboardProps {
    loggedInUserData: ILoggedInUserData;
}

const PaceLabsDashboard = ({ loggedInUserData }: DashboardProps): JSX.Element => {
    // const [loggedInUserData, setLoggedInUserData] = useState<ILoggedInUserData>();
    console.log(loggedInUserData.name);

    return (
        <Box>
            {/* Header */}
            <Box sx={{ width: "100%", height: "72px" }}>
                <DashboardHeader username={loggedInUserData.name} />
            </Box>

            <Grid container sx={{ display: "flex", height: "900px", width: "100%", textAlign: "center" }}>
                {/* Right content */}
                <Grid item sx={{ border: "2px solid black", width: "70%" }}>
                    <LeadershipProfile />
                </Grid>
```

And the routes file with the lines where the error appears:

```js
 {
        path: "/my-dashboard",
        element: <PaceLabsDashboard />,
 }
```

This is the ILoggedInUserData:

```js
export interface ILoggedInUserData {
    userId: number;
    name: string;
    username: string;
    lastLoggedInDate: number;
    groupId: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PaceLabsDashboard Component , You are TypeChecking with props named LoggedinUserdata..

PaceLabsDashboard need to pass loggedinuserdata as Props.

```
  {
        path: "/my-dashboard",
        element: <PaceLabsDashboard loggedinuserdata={\\ structure of ILoggedInUserData} />,
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, since this is the first project using React and typescript that I work on... what do you mean by passing the interface ILoggedInUserData structure?

Comment: For example.. your interface looks like an  object with username as value..  you have to pass..      eg: <PaceLabsDashboard loggedinuserdata = { username: "string" } />

Comment: Please share the IloggedinUserdata types value too..

Comment: Ok, I added the ILoggedInUserInterface to the question.